# Sybase/isql/Transact-SQL - how to terminate sql on same line

Tags: sybase

I have a query that is generating further queries, things like this:

```
select 'exec uspd_thing "'||name||'"'
from sometable
```

Which produces this :

```
exec uspd_thing "name1"
exec uspd_thing "name2"
```

But isql requires a 'go' statement after each statement.

There is an option to change the command terminator (-c) but the new terminator still needs to appear on the same line.

Any suggestions/tips on how to do this kind of thing... I guess I could post-process the results to add the 'go' lines...

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK ISQL doesn't always need a go (or a ";", which will equally serve as a terminator.
T-SQL commands may be allocated on consecutive lines without separator, the parser will handle that.

R. Pods

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the go in the result:

```
select 'exec uspd_thing "'||name||'"'||char(10)||'go'||char(10)
from sometable
```

Answer (score 0):

The post-process option via awk is as follows:

```
awk '{print $0}; /exec / {print "go"}'
```